# Generate a random number that is not in array

Tags: java, arrays

so I have this code that basically reads from a text file. The text file contains 9 rows of 9 random numbers, as well as 9 columns - it is for a 9 x 9 Sudoku puzzle, so think of it that way.

Here is what the text file that is being read in looks like:

```
1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1
0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0
0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1
```

For this particular facet, the values from the file are used to determine if a cell is empty is or not. If it is a number 1, than that cell will contain some sort of value, but if the number is 0, that cell is empty, and will need to have a random number generated for it.

How do I make it so that when Math.random is used to generate said random number, it checks to see if that same number is already in that row, and if it is, generate a new one?

Here is the code. Thanks in advance...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;

public class RandomNumberGenerator {

// set Sudoku value rows to unchangeable number 9
private static final int ROWS = 9;
// set columns to unchangeable number 9
private static final int COLUMNS = 9;

public static void main(String[] args) { // main

    // load in text file
    ReadSudokuFile puzzle = new ReadSudokuFile("puzzle.txt");
    // set array to get number values from getDisplayValues method
    int puzzleNumbers[][] = puzzle.getDisplayValues();

        // rows loop
        for (int rows = 0; rows < ROWS; rows++) {
            // columns loop
            for (int columns = 0; columns < COLUMNS; columns++) {
                // A cell containing the number 0 is an empty input box in Sudoku grid
                if (puzzleNumbers[rows][columns] == 0) {
                    // populate that empty input box to a random number between 1 and 9
                    puzzleNumbers[rows][columns] = (int)((Math.random() * 9) + 1);  // cast Math.random as an int & add 1 so a zero doesn't display
                }
            } // end columns loop
            // print out the array to console
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(puzzleNumbers[rows]));
        } // end rows loop

    } // end main

}
```

There is another file that this file pulls info from, but it is not relevant here for this specific question. Thanks again!

Comment: Sudoku has rules, you can't just put random numbers anywhere.

Comment: so what is your problem? you dunno how to generate a random number? dunno how to read a file? dunno how to turn your text data to 2-d array? dunno how to check if a value is `1` in your array?

Comment: I am having trouble figuring out how to generate a new random number in a specific cell if that number was already generated from Math.random, as stated in the question. I thought it was something simple, not so complex like the answers below.

Comment: @lushmoney I've added a solution that's a single statement. Let me know if you have any issues understanding how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible method, using Java 8, is to filter members of the row from a stream of random numbers. Something like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
puzzleNumbers[row][col] = rand.ints(0, 10)
    .filter(n -> Arrays.binarySearch(puzzleNumbers[row], 0, col, n) < 0)
    .findAny().get();
```

I've left out the `row` and `col` iteration for clarity.

This can be extended fairly easily to filter out numbers in the row or 3x3 cell. Let me know in comments if you want examples for those.

Comment: Very clever way of using lambda and search

Answer (score 0):

well you can make a private method that checks that.

```
 public boolean checkRow(int row,int generatedNum){

        boolean flag = true;
        for (int columns = 0; columns < COLUMNS; columns++) {
                // A cell containing the number 0 is an empty input box in Sudoku grid
                if (puzzleNumbers[row][columns] == generatedNum) {
               flag = false;
               break;
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: if this is true you have found a good generated number. when false generate a new number

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an ArrayList with the numbers from 1 to 9 and the get a random index. When you need start over, you can just reset the ArrayList.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

        // Populate the ArrayList with numbers ( from 1 to 9 )
        resetNumbers(numbers);

        // Getting 5 random numbers from 1 to 9
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println(getRandomIndex(numbers));
        }

        // Reset the number list
        resetNumbers(numbers);
        System.out.println();

        // Get another 9 random numbers from 1 to 9
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            System.out.println(getRandomIndex(numbers));
        }
    }

    public static void resetNumbers(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
        list.clear();

        populateList(list, 1, 9);
    }

    public static void populateList(ArrayList<Integer> list, int from, int to) {
        for (int i = from; i <= to; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
    }

    public static int getRandomIndex(ArrayList<Integer> numbers) {
        int index = (int)((Math.random() * numbers.size()) + 0);
        int result = numbers.get(index);

        numbers.remove(index);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: These are all great answers, but I was thinking something along the lines of that I'm just missing some kind of while loop or do while loop that will do the trick. Didn't realize it would be so complex. I'll have to relook at everything then. Thanks for your help tho...

Comment: Using a loop to look if a random number is already in your array is not a good idea. You gonna have performance issues. For example the first random number you get is 8 but it is in the array already, and you get another number, but still you get 8 another time.. well imagine this kind of loop for every number. And its possible to get the same number 1,2,3,4... times in a row

Comment: If you dont know how Lists work ... you can always replace the list with an array.